# Making an API throw HTTP errors or return empty objects

Tags: json, http, asp.net-core, angular7

Is is more elegant to make a JSON-API return plain HTTP error codes or empty arrays/objects as JSON to a frontend?
Example:
1. Frontend legitimately requests a user profile.
2. The custom permission system implementation determines that this user is not permitted to access the profile and returns `403` (backend-side).
3. Frontend uses a try/catch-like syntax in various places just to interpret the error code.

The used frameworks are ASP.NET Core  and Angular (to specify the context).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on the error and status code. In general, you should not return things like an empty array or empty object, unless that's literally the result. For example, if someone requests a list of `Foo`s for example, and there's literally none, then it would be appropriate to return an empty array. That would be a successful 200, though.

For something like a 403, you should either return no body or if you do return a body, it should be an error object, such as a [problem details](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807) response - not empty.

A 403 is a bit of a special case, as the status code itself is generally descriptive enough, and there may not even be additional information to add. In other words, the client is forbidden; it's generally not important *why*, and there's generally no way to correct it, assuming they've authenticated. In cases where there's no real way to recover or the reasons for the result are unimportant or obvious, then you can return no response body at all. In all other cases, you should return "something", even if it's just a simple string message, in order to help the client understand what happened.

Empty arrays/objects should be reserved for when the actual result is an empty array/object, and that's all.